# Core Data - How to validate the uniqueness of an attribute within the scope of

Tags: iphone, validation, core-data

I would like to know how to implement a validation in Core Data.  What I'd like to do is ensure that an attribute is unique within the scope of a related parent object.  In other words, I'm wondering how to implement the `validates_uniqueness_of :field, :scope => :parent` paradigm (from rails / activerecord) in Core Data.

For example, suppose I create two models - one called Blog and one called Post. Each Post has an attribute called `title`.  Different Blog objects can have Posts with identical titles, but how do I validate the uniqueness of a `title` within the scope of a Blog?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Walk the relationship to the parent and grab the set of posts.  Then you can run a predicate against it to check for uniqueness like:

```
NSSet *set = [[self parent] posts];
NSSet *filtered = [set filteredSetWithPredicate:[NSPredicate preicateWithFormat:@"self != %@ and title == %@", self, [self title]]];
if ([filtered count] > 0) return NO;
return YES;
```